# python script for android scripting environment

Tags: python, android, api, scripting

so i have this script that i pulled from a website, and am trying to get a barcode scanner working... the site says it can be done in these 6 lines of python:

```
import android
droid = android.Android()
code = droid.scanBarcode()
isbn = int(code['result']['SCAN_RESULT'])
url = ?http://books.google.com?q=%d? % isbn
droid.startActivity(?android.intent.action.VIEW?, url)
```

and i am getting a syntax error a the first '?' in the url. can anyone help me figure this out? i have no experience in python or the android api.

Answer (score 1):

Change all the ? to " might work. I guess when you copy from the website, something funny happens.

Comment: that was it, wow i should have been able to figure that one out... lol thanks for the quick response